# Laravel Homestead Vagrant Box Database Problems

Tags: mysql, laravel, vagrant

I can't use the same database.php settings when browsing the local website in a browser (example.app:8000) and when using php artisan migrate.

If my database.php settings are:

```
'mysql' => array(
   'driver'    => 'mysql',
   'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
   'database'  => 'homestead',
   'username'  => 'homestead',
   'password'  => 'secret',
   'charset'   => 'utf8',
   'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
   'prefix'    => '',
   'port'      => '33060'
)
```

Artisan works but I get this when browsing the site:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'
>   (111) (View: /home/vagrant/Code/playnamics/app/views/hello.blade.php)

If my database.php settingd are:

```
'mysql' => array(
   'driver'    => 'mysql',
   'host'      => 'localhost',
   'database'  => 'homestead',
   'username'  => 'homestead',
   'password'  => 'secret',
   'charset'   => 'utf8',
   'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
   'prefix'    => '',
   'port'      => '33060'
)
```

Browsing the site works but artisan give this error:

> [PDOException]                                       SQLSTATE[HY000]
>   [2002] No such file or directory

**Basically, I need the host set to localhost when browsing and 127.0.0.1 when using artisan. How can I simply use the same host so I don't have to keep changing the value every 2 minutes?**

Really confused. Seemed simpler before I started using homestead & vagrant... :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what I answered in the Laracasts forums, in case it helps:

Inside the VM the sql port is 3306. Outside of the VM the host machine just has a forward to the SQL port on the VM. That is why 33060 points to 3306.

Unfortunately that is why you can't use the same database stanza for both.

Two ideas come to mind:

1. Change the sql port from 33060 to be 3306 also on the host inside the homestead.rb file. I know machines get picky if you choose something under port 10000 so you might get prompted for admin credentials (if it even lets you). As long as you are not running something on that port it "should" work.
2. You might consider setting up two Laravel environments for when working outside of the VM and one for inside. That way, you can override the database.php settings for when running artisan commands on the VM or if running artisan on the Host. In reality, you only care about changing the port number since all other settings would be identical. You can leave everything else as it is.

Just something to try. I just leave a SSH session open to the VM and run commands there since connecting to it is pretty fast after resuming the machine.

Comment: SSH'ing into the VM and running artisan commands is def. the easiest way to go.

Comment: the second idea is great, I created a development environment for me to run migrate at my host machine

Answer (score 4):

The way that I do this is set variables in the `homestead.yml` file. PhpDotenv doesn't populate the values if they exist so you can set the environment variables on the Homestead VM and config

```
# homestead.yml

variables:
 - key: APP_ENV
   value: local
 - key: DB_HOST
   value: 127.0.0.1
 - key: DB_PORT
   value: 3306

# .env

DB_HOST=192.168.10.10 # Homestead VM IP
DB_PORT=33060         # Port which is forwarded to 3306 on the VM
```

--

> vagrant@homestead:~/Sites/example$ php artisan migrate
>
> Nothing to migrate.

--

> Ben in ~/Sites/example on develop$ php artisan migrate
>
> Nothing to migrate.

This obviously makes the assumption that all sites running on Homestead are using MySQL (or some database on 3306) and all databases are on the Homestead VM, as opposed to on the host, or at a 3rd party, say AWS etc.

At the time of writing, homestead doesn't allow you to configure per site variables.

Answer (score 3):

You have to execute the migration command from inside the VM. First, you log into the VM:

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
```

After that, you just cd into your project's folder and run the migration

```
cd Code/blog
php artisan migrate
```

The reason why this happens is because localhost:3306 from the perspective of your machine is one thing, from inside the VM is another.

Comment: If you are using vagrant then just do vagrant ssh

Answer (score 2):

In homestead, MySQL is configured to bind to the VM's 10.x.x.x address, and does not bind to 127.0.0.1

You can change this by editing `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and adding the line:

`bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

This will allow you to use 127.0.0.1 in your database configuration for both web and CLI use of the database.

Answer (score 0):

After using homestead ssh and paste your ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 our php artisan migrate working properly

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix:

1. ssh into your homestead virtual machine (`homestead ssh`)
2. navigate to the project directory
3. run your command from there (`php artisan migrate`)

Answer (score 0):

Ben Swinburne's answer worked for me.

I added the following to my Homestead.yaml file

```
variables:
 - key: APP_ENV
   value: local
 - key: DB_HOST
   value: 127.0.0.1
 - key: DB_PORT
   value: 3306
```

This updates what our code uses to connect to mysql from within the VM.  Because they are set within the VM, they will take precedence over what is in the .env file.  I believe values within the .env file are only set if they don't already exist within the server environment variables.

Then within the .env running on the host machine, I have what is needed to connect to mysql from the outside of the VM going in.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

Now, I can use `artisan migrate` outside of the VM and inside the VM without any connection and port issues.  Browsing the website also works as expected.