# Laravel 5.1 - Homestead MySQL connection. `Connection Refused` & `No such file or directory`

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, homestead

When my .env file is like this:

```
 DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
 DB_DATABASE=homestead
 DB_USERNAME=homestead
 DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

**Terminal `php artisan migrate` works successful but on localhost test, it throws**:

> PDOException in Connector.php line 50:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

But when my .env file is like this:

```
 DB_HOST=localhost
 DB_DATABASE=homestead
 DB_USERNAME=homestead
 DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

**On localhost everything (registration) works well however `php artisan migrate` on terminal throws:**

> [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

My database.php file:

```
      'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
        'port'      => '33060',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside the VM the sql port is 3306. Outside of the homestead VM the host machine just has a forward to the SQL port on the homestead VM. That is why 33060 points to 3306.

[Laravel Homestead Vagrant Box Database Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048461/laravel-homestead-vagrant-box-database-problems)

Comment: Also the host should be 127.0.0.1 not localhost .

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue. Do the following:

.env

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 
 DB_PORT=3306
 DB_DATABASE=homestead
 DB_USERNAME=homestead
 DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

database.php

```
  'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
        'port'      => env('DB_PORT', 3306),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

That will get your browsing fixed. Now to run artisan commands, just do vagrant SSH and run them on the VM.