# Laravel 5.7 migrate error : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: laravel, homestead, migrate

I'm using homestead for laravel.
I had installed 2 virtual web site. Two website DB is working good when I tried to migrate. But today I created new website and try to migrate I took error looks like below.

Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = test and table_name = migrations)

---

and this is my .env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:2ZFx67Hrfao+ngk6hmyjDPmmXPiz4hXejJ5ncMqeX5E=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://test.app

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

---

and this is homestead.yaml file

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

ssl: true

folders:
    - map: ~/Dev/sites/test
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/test

    - map: ~/Dev/sites/cvms
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/cvms

    - map: ~/Dev/sites/poms
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/poms

sites:
    - map: test.app
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/test/public

    - map: cvms.app
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/cvms/public

    - map: poms.app
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/poms/public

databases:
    - test
    - cvms
    - poms
```

---

Of course, that is same before two site's config except DB_DATEBASE item.

I can't understand why It takes error.

and sorry my terrible English....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.1 - Homestead MySQL connection. \`Connection Refused\` & \`No such file or directory\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926383/laravel-5-1-homestead-mysql-connection-connection-refused-no-such-file-o)

Answer (score 0):

Try to access your `.env` file. Check that all the DB names/creditentials are correct as your phpadmin suggests.

`DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`

Answer (score -1):

Try running the `php artisan migrate` command from within the virtual machine.
As notified on [Laravel's docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#running-migrations).