# Connection refused - Laravel, remote database

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

In my local environment inserting data into my database works. However on my remote server it does not work.

I have changed my remote .env and database.php files so that my remote database and server should work. I am able to connect to the database via `mysqlworkbench`, without any problems.

However I am getting the following error:

> exception: "Illuminate\Database\QueryException"
>   file: "/var/www/html/go/releases/1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php"
>       line: 664
>       message: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: insert into `temp_users` (`energy`, `diet`, `car`, `shortFlights`, `longFlights`, `email`, `country`, `total`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1.13, 1.7, 0.55, 0, 0, test51@mail.com, Netherlands, 5.38, 2019-09-10 15:27:41, 2019-09-10 15:27:41))"
>       trace: [,…]

.env (replaced some values with defaults, to protect privacy).

```
APP_NAME=thename
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=the key
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=error
APP_URL=theurl

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=thedatabasename
DB_USERNAME=theusername
DB_PASSWORD=thepassword

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=localhost
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

database.php (important section)

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'thedatabasename'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'theusername'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'thepassword'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

The database name is correct. The table exists, and all the fields do too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: change DB_HOST as your remote server IP instead of localhost

Comment: @PalakJadav I still have the same issue when I change both `DB_HOST` to my ip.

Comment: run command php artisan config:clear

Comment: It tells me `Could not open input file: artisan`. I have never used php artisan for local development either.

Comment: this may help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048461/laravel-homestead-vagrant-box-database-problems

Comment: @Otto are you using homestead?

Comment: @UdoE. for my local server I am using homestead. However this error only appears on my remote server.

Comment: Check your mysql permissions for the user `DB_USERNAME`

Comment: @Otto, vagrant with homestead I guess?

Comment: @UdoE. yes vagrant with homestead

Comment: where are you running `php artisan` command from?

Comment: @UdoE. I am never running php artisan, when testing locally I run `npm run watch`

Comment: @ljubadr how can I check this? I have 1 user, which is the user shown above. And I set this line of permissions: `GRANT ALL ON laravel.* TO 'laraveluser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'` - an example.

Comment: @UdoE. I apologize, I am using VirtualBox with homestead.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your remote access to your remote DB is not available so to do that please open your terminal and run these commands.

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

. . .
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
. . .
```

By default, this value is set to 127.0.0.1, meaning that the server will only look for local connections. You will need to change this directive to reference an external IP address. For the purposes of troubleshooting, you could set this directive to a wildcard IP address, either *, ::, or 0.0.0.0:

Update your
. . .
bind-address            =  0.0.0.0
. . .
Run
sudo systemctl restart mysql
Then

```
mysql -u username -p
RENAME USER 'sammy'@'localhost' TO 'sammy'@'remote_server_ip';
CREATE USER 'sammy'@'remote_server_ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT CREATE, ALTER, DROP, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT, REFERENCES, RELOAD on *.* TO 'sammy'@'remote_server_ip' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit
sudo ufw allow from remote_IP_address to any port 3306
sudo ufw allow 3306
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @PalakJadav rightly pointed out, `DB_HOST` in your *remote* `.env` file should be changed to the remote IP or hostname of your remote database server. Also check with your database service provider that the other parameters are correct as well.

After you make changes to your `.env` file,  enter your remote server via secured shell. From your remote server root directory, run the `php artisan` command to reload your laravel configuration

```
 php artisan config:cache
```

clear old cached configuration

```
 php artisan config:clear
```

Finally, clear your application cache

```
 php artisan cache:clear
```

You can now retry your mysql query.

**Update**

Also remember to migrate your tables when you first put you application online

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Ok, however why do I need to reset my local cache? can this impact my remote server? Just asking because the problem is never local, just on the remote server. Somehow the connection to the database is refused, and I have indeed changed  my `DB_HOST` and it didnt change anything. All the login details etc, are correct and should be working. Thanks in advance. On my remote server Nginx is used.

Comment: Your old configuration is cached. So, after you apply the correct changes to the `.env` file, the cached configuration is still used. You aren't resetting you local cache, you are reloading it to reflect the changes made in your `.env` file

Comment: Ok interesting, however if I have manually replaced my remote .env file does it still use the cache?

Comment: I cleared my cache and deployed it to my server. However it gives me the same error.

Comment: Oh! I tought you were only connecting to a remote database provider. If you are hosting your files remotely as well, this has nothing to do with local server. Update your remote `.env` file and if you can ssh into your remote server, clear the cache there. Sorry, I didn't get your question clearly.

Comment: Yeah so I updated my `.env` to the suggestion made above (with the rest of the settings shown above) and I can `ssh` into my server, cleared the cache in my files. And it still fails sadly.

Comment: Then some of your credentials to your database might be incorrect. Can you access your database via a GUI - phpmyadmin for example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199263/discussion-between-otto-and-udo-e).

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was facing was that my `mysql` `user` did not have the correct permissions.

Finally I changed it to login to mysql with the `root` --> which is how I figured out the permissions were missing on the `user`.

Make sure to set `GRANT ALL ON laravel_database.* TO 'laravel_user'@'localhost';` to the user you are logging in with.

***spelling is very important!!!*** because I just had 1 typo and it frustrated me for days.